# How to fix 'Error creating document instance. Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;Attribute "class" must be declared for element type "mapper".'

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to config mapper interface in sql configuration xml. How to do that?

Please help me. This is my sql configuration xml:

```
<configuration>
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"></transactionManager>

        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myBatis"/>
            <property name="username" value="root"/>
            <property name="password" value="root"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
<mappers>
    <mapper class="Student_mapper"/>
</mappers>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [mybatis documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers), I think that you have to put class name with its full package name.

Here's an example from the docs.

```xml
<!-- Using mapper interface classes -->
<mappers>
  <mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.AuthorMapper"/>
  <mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.BlogMapper"/>
  <mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.PostMapper"/>
</mappers>
```

Comment: Is it in default package? If yes, that's not a correct structure then. Try to structure your application that way.